# how to use columns from outer query in subquery to get result from another table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to get an aggregate result using a subquery from a table against each row of another table in hive. I understand that hive does not support subquery in SELECT clause so I'm trying to use the subquery in FROM clause, but it seems that hive does not support correlated subqueries as well.

Here's the example: table A contains data of accounts transactions with columns of dates(d1 and d2) and a currency column along with other columns, what I want  to do is get the sum of exchange rate values in table B(which contains currency rates for each day of the year) between dates d1 and d2 for each account. I'm trying something like this:

```
SELECT 
    account_no, currn, balance, 
    trans_date as d2, last_trans_date as d1, exchng_rt 
FROM 
    acc AS A, 
    (SELECT sum(rate) exchng_rt 
     FROM currency 
     WHERE curr_type = A.currn 
       AND banking_date BETWEEN A.d1 AND A.d2) AS B
```

Here is sample, the table A has account transactions and dates like:

```
account    balance    trans_date    last_trans_date    currency
abc        100        20-12-2016    20-11-2016          USD
abc        200        25-12-2016    20-12-2016          USD
def        500        15-11-2015    10-11-2015          AUD
def        600        20-11-2015    15-11-2015          AUD
```

and the table B is something like:

```
curr_type     rate    banking_date
USD           50.9    01-01-2016
USD           50.2    02-01-2016
USD           50.5    03-01-2016
AUD           50.9    01-01-2016
AUD           50.2    02-01-2016
AUD           50.5    03-01-2016  and so on...
```

so table contains daily rates of currencies for each type of currency

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do what you want using `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.account_no, a.currn, a.balance, a.trans_date as d2, a.last_trans_date as d1,
       SUM(rate) as exchng_rt 
FROM acc a LEFT JOIN
     currency c
     ON c.curr_type = a.currn and banking_date between A.d1 and A.d2
GROUP BY a.account_no, a.currn, a.balance, a.trans_date, a.last_trans_date;
```

Comment: can't really use group by as the table contains multiple entries for each account no. and i want to get exchange rate for each transaction entry or row separately

Comment: @Atif . . . There are multiple `group by` keys, so that shouldn't be a problem.  If you have a primary key, throw that into the `group by` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the filter after joining the two tables, something like the following:

```
SELECT  A.account_no,
        A.currn, 
        A.balance,
        A.trans_date as d2,
        A.last_trans_date as d1, 
        B.exchng_rt 
FROM acc as A
JOIN (SELECT sum(rate) as exchng_rt,
         curr_type,
         banking_date
    FROM currency group by curr_type,
         banking_date ) as B
ON A.currn = curr_type 
WHERE B.banking_date between A.d1 and A.d2</code>
```

Comment: the group will not give the desired results as the currency table has record for each day and i want to get exchange rates between a specified period

Comment: Doesn't the banking_date equate to a day? the subquery is grouped by banking_date and the outer query is filtered by the same field. What am I missing here?